# Plotting a time series data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have a time series sequence data with Date on one column, and the ID of agents in the second column.

```
    pAgent  Date    Year    Month   Day Week-Day
0   27918   2019-11-28  2019    11  28  3
1   1286    2019-11-28  2019    11  28  3
2   1314    2019-11-28  2019    11  28  3
3   21342   2019-12-01  2019    12  1   6
4   5344    2019-11-28  2019    11  28  3
5   23841   2019-11-28  2019    11  28  3
6   22596   2019-11-28  2019    11  28  3
.   ..      ...         ..      ..  ..  ..
.   ..      ...         ..      ..  ..  ..
```

How do I plot the occurrence of an agent, say pAgent = 22596, for an entire month?

Comment: What have you tried ? Your work is not showcased at all!

Comment: @solenya
Plotting the series for the entire month is relatively straight forward.
`plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))`
`pagent_transactions.index = pagent_transactions['Date']`
`sns.lineplot(data=pagent_transactions['pAgent'])`

I am stuck in plotting the event for a particular agent.

Comment: You could have added that in the question!

Answer (score 1):

### You can create Gantt chart like this,

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
df = pd.DataFrame({'pAgent' :[22596,22596,44456,6655,22596,22596,42244,22596,22596,22596] ,'day':  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  })
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
axes.scatter(df[df['pAgent'] == 22596]['day'], df[df['pAgent'] == 22596]['pAgent'], marker = '|',s=10**3)
axes.set(xlabel='days')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a simple data handling error, and I was able to resolve it finally. Here's the solution to the issue:

```
count = file_name[file_name['pAgent'] == 27918].groupby("Day").count().reset_index()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = sns.pointplot("Day","pAgent",data=count,color="white",markers="H")
plt.axhline(avg_curr["pAgent"].mean(),color="k",
            linestyle="dotted",linewidth=2,label="average transaction flow")
```

[image: Image-Chart]